# Matlab line code error

Tags: matlab, input

we use matlab to analyse our hrv results of heart patients.We were able to get the waveform we required but however it shows error in code line 67. kindly help.

```
x1 = load('ecg3.dat'); 
x2=x1; fs = 1000; % Sampling rate
N = length (x2); % Silength
t = [0:N-1]/fs; % tiidx
figure(1)

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x1)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title('Input ECG Signal')
% Cancellation DC drift and normalization
x1 = x1 - mean (x1 ); % cancel DC conponents
x1 = x1/ max( abs(x1 )); % normalize to one

subplot(4,1,2)
plot(t,x1)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title(' ECG Signal after cancellation DC drift and 
normalization')
% Low Pass Filtering
b=[1 0 0 0 0 0 -2 0 0 0 0 0 1]; a=[1 -2 1];
h_LP=filter(b,a,[1 zeros(1,12)]); % transfer function of LPF
x2 = conv (x1 ,h_LP);
x2 = x2 (6+[1: N]); %cancel delay
x2 = x2/ max( abs(x2 )); % normalize , for convenience .

subplot(4,1,3)
plot([0:length(x2)-1]/fs,x2)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title(' ECG Signal after LPF')
xlim([0 max(t)])
% High Pass Filtering
b = [-1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 -32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];
a = [1 -1];
h_HP=filter(b,a,[1 zeros(1,32)]); % impulse response of HPF
x3 = conv (x2 ,h_HP);
x3 = x3/ max( abs(x3 ));

subplot(4,1,4)
plot([0:length(x3)-1]/fs,x3)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title(' ECG Signal after HPF')**LINE67**
xlim([0 max(t)])
% Derivative Filter
% Make impulse response
h = [-1 -2 0 2 1]/8;
% Apply filter

x4 = conv (x3 ,h);
x4 = x4 (2+[1: N]);
x4 = x4/ max( abs(x4 ));
figure(2)

subplot(4,1,1)
plot([0:length(x4)-1]/fs,x4)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title(' ECG Signal after Derivative')
% Squaring
x5 = x4 .^2;
x5 = x5/ max( abs(x5 ));

subplot(4,1,2)
plot([0:length(x5)-1]/fs,x5)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title(' ECG Signal Squarting')
% Moving Window Integration
% Make impulse response
h = ones (1 ,31)/31;
Delay = 15; % Delay in samples
% Apply filter
x6 = conv (x5 ,h);
x6 = x6 (15+[1: N]);
x6 = x6/ max( abs(x6 ));

subplot(4,1,3)
plot([0:length(x6)-1]/fs,x6)
xlabel('second');ylabel('Volts');title(' ECG Signal after Averaging')
% Find QRS Points Which it is different than Pan-Tompkins algorithm
max_h = max(x6);
thresh = mean (x6);
poss_reg =(x6>thresh*max_h)';
left = find(diff([0 poss_reg'])==1);
right = find(diff([poss_reg' 0])==-1);
left=left-(6+15); % cancel delay because of LP and HP
right=right-(6+15);% cancel delay because of LP and HP
left=abs(left);
right=abs(right);
for i=1:length(left)
[R_value(i) R_loc(i)] = max( x1(left(i):right(i)) );
R_loc(i) = R_loc(i)-1+left(i); % add offset
[Q_value(i) Q_loc(i)] = min( x1(left(i):R_loc(i)) );
Q_loc(i) = Q_loc(i)-1+left(i); % add offset
[S_value(i) S_loc(i)] = min( x1(left(i):right(i)) );
S_loc(i) = S_loc(i)-1+left(i); % add offset

end

subplot(4,1,4)
plot (t,x1,t(R_loc) ,R_value , 'r^')
% there is no selective wave
Q_loc=Q_loc(find(Q_loc~=0));
R_loc=R_loc(find(R_loc~=0));
S_loc=S_loc(find(S_loc~=0));

values=x2(R_loc);
% 1 beat/sec x 60 sec/min = 60 beats/min. 
%%R-R interval using diffrence operation method

tiscl=t(2)-t(1);
px=diff(R_loc);
d_tms=find(diff(R_loc)>200);
d_men=mean(px(d_tms)); 
beat=d_men*tiscl;
heart_rate=1/beat*60;
fprintf('%2.1f seconds/beat\n',beat);
rs=sprintf('Heart Rate= %2.1f beats per minit \n',heart_rate);

**
```

> ???Error using ==> horzcat
>
> ```
> CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
>
> Error in ==> Untitled at 67 
>
> left = find(diff([0 poss_reg']) ==1);
> ```

**

> this is the error message recieved is at sub plot (4,1,4) ,dont know how to rectify this
>   error. kindly help as our project is paused due to this.

Comment: thanks mark , i just added code block and indicated code 67 . We are finding difficulties because we are not used to programming and yet we came through it here. now we are stuck ,kindly help us.

Comment: As High Performance Mark already said - please also post your error message.

Comment: sincere apologies , forgot that. will include right away.

Comment: sure will do it right away mark . :)

Comment: mark i have done as u asked. i have given the error message and also did the spacing as much as i could understand. sry new to this . kindly help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message has nothing to do with " sub plot (4,1,4)". `[0 poss_reg']` is what is causing the error. `horzcat` means "horizontal concatenation", which is what you're trying to do there. However, `poss_reg'` is probably a column. Therefore, you can't horizontally concatenate it with zero.  (See `help horzcat` for more info).

One option if you're not sure if you're going to have a row or column vector is to use (:) to force column orientation and `vertcat` it:

```
[0; poss_reg(:)]
```

More generally speaking, you should use `dbstop if error` or other MATLAB debugging tools and examine the sizes and types of your variables at the point where the error occurs.

Comment: thanks so much mate for taking your time in answering. let me check this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
left  = find(diff([0; poss_reg],1,1)==1);  % remember to zero pad at start
right = find(diff([poss_reg; 0],1,1)==-1); % remember to zero pad at end
```

good luck!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?